# How to show loading of content from YouTube?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube

I have a UIViewController with a UIScrollView inside it. This scroll view contains a few strings and images, and more recently it's own UIWebView which contains a YouTube video.

As a first case, assuming the user has Internet access, how should I show the user that the box contains content that is currently loading?

Musings:

I was able to place a UIView on top of this UIWebView (within the scroll view) which contained a UILabel with the text "Loading..." inside it. But I was unable to remove/hide the label based on when the video has fully appeared as I could not get viewDidAppear et al to respond. I also have access to a BOOL which tells me if the user has Internet access or not, so the other side to the question would be to set the same label to explain that they have no web access if that is true. (which would explain the presence of a white box in this scroll view)

I also looked at whether it'd be possible to write a custom responder to fire off when the video thumbnail in the web view had finished loading, but again I couldn't get any of the responder methods to be hit for this to work.

In short, how should I be tackling this problem? Thanks in advance for any advice or assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your view controller as the web view's `delegate`. The UIWebViewDelegate protocol defines two methods, `-webViewDidStartLoad:` and `-webViewDidFinishLoad:`, that you should be able to use to track when the page has begun to load and (hopefully) when the thumbnail has appeared.

Comment: Thanks for this - they are now responding as I would have expected. Seems earlier I was putting them in the wrong place. Both of these responders are firing twice though - is this now likely due to the UIWebView subclass I have written and the way it works?

Comment: Very possibly. I guess you can just set a flag in an instance variable on your delegate class and ignore the second set of messages.